# Excel VBA & TextToColumns stops after blank rows

Tags: vba, excel

I am using texttocolumns method to split the columns, seperating them by comma. Below is the code for the same.

```
Dim rownum As Long
rownum = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox rownum
Range("C7:C" & rownum).CurrentRegion.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("C7:C" & rownum), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
                    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, other:=False
```

Now here I have around 60K rows but above code stops splitting after 40K as there are two blank rows are there after it and then again have data rows.

Is there anyways we can use texttocolumns here which can ignore blank rows as well or any other logic is welcomed.

Comment: Try removing the `CurrentRegion`

Comment: Excellent, this has really worked thanks